# error when trying to insert varchar primary key into mysql through spring mvc app

Tags: mysql, sql, spring, spring-mvc

I am getting the following error message in the command line when I try to run my spring mvc app on tomcat server from within eclipse:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:  
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DataSourceInitializer#0':
Invocation of init method failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException:  
Failed to execute database script;  
nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: 
Failed to execute SQL script statement at line 68 of resource class path resource[db/mysql/populateDB.sql]: 
INSERT IGNORE INTO codes('99503', 'Home visit for respiratory therapy care')
```

Note that the line of code that is throwing the error is:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO codes('99503', 'Home visit for respiratory therapy care');
```

The code that creates the codes table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS codes(
  code VARCHAR(100) PRIMARY KEY,
  description VARCHAR(500)
)engine=InnoDB;
```

How do I fix the code so that I can get past this error?  My guess is that it has something to do with the syntax required when inserting a VARCHAR primary key into MySQL, but I am not certain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the correct syntax.  Here is one way:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO cpt_codes
    select '99503', 'Home visit for respiratory therapy care';
```

You should actually specify the column names:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO cpt_codes(col1, col2)
    select '99503', 'Home visit for respiratory therapy care';
```

Comment: Thank you. +1 for trying to help.  You might be right.  However, I found that the problem was fixed when I added the word VALUES as follows: INSERT IGNORE INTO codes VALUES ('99503', 'Home visit for respiratory therapy care');